# Expected improvement compared with probability of improvement and lower confidence bound

Tags: bayesian, optimization, modeling, bayesian-optimization

From all the references i read so far, i have been seeing Expected improvement being commonly used as acquisition function. Why is that so, compared with the other two i mentioned in the title/question.

Comment: it's simple and it can be computed in closed form. isn't this enough for wide adoption?